# array get element by index data structure in java

Tags: arrays, data-structures

In array, we know, we are getting element by providing index. Can someone explore what data structure used to achieve this mechanism? is there any mapping in memory or hashing or indexing like used in DB?

Comment: They are stored contiguously. Array elements are accessed by computing the memory address by calculating the offset based on element size

Comment: sir, can you please explain with example

Comment: Depends on the language; JavaScript is a good counter-example.

Comment: It is simple, just like mathematical formula.

Consider one dim array ARR of N integer(2 byte memory for each element) stored in memory.

Now, to find address of ARR[i]:

Adddress(ARR[i]) = Base Address + No. Of bytes for each element * (Find index - Lower bound of ARR)

Here, 

Base Address = starting address of array 
No. Of bytes for each element  = for integer, it is 2 bytes
Find index = which element you are searching in an array
Lower bound of ARR = lower bound  index .  for more info: http://sachin4java.blogspot.in/2018/02/find-and-calculate-address-in-array-for.html

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, just like mathematical formula.

for more info: http://sachin4java.blogspot.in/2018/02/find-and-calculate-address-in-array-for.html